# Flask blueprint doesn't work (Python2)

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

**Setup:**
I am trying to clone git [project(all the code here)](https://github.com/BrOrlandi/SFECommerce) to locally deploy it and make it work for academic purpose.
So far I have only had experience with Flask under Python 3, but this project is written on Flask using Python 2. After setting up virtualenv, installing all requirements I can successfully run(python server.py) it and navigate to index page.

**Problem:** Whenever i try to reach pages like "localhost:5000/login" I can only see 404 error "Not Found". Looking through the code I see that it is importing blueprints which contain routes to ".../login" view, but it doesn't get to a point of showing it.

Project structure looks like this:

```
.
├── API Documentation.md
├── app.py
├── app.pyc
├── data
│   ├── samples
│   │   ├── categories.txt
│   │   ├── domains.txt
│   │   ├── names.txt
│   │   ├── products.txt
│   │   └── surnames.txt
│   └── sql
│       └── schema-00.sql
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── server.py
├── sfec
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── base.pyc
│   │   ├── decorators.py
│   │   ├── decorators.pyc
│   │   ├── fields.py
│   │   ├── fields.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── order.py
│   │   ├── order.pyc
│   │   ├── product.py
│   │   ├── product.pyc
│   │   ├── user.py
│   │   └── user.pyc
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── config.pyc
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── decorators.py
│   │   ├── decorators.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── order.py
│   │   ├── order.pyc
│   │   ├── user.py
│   │   └── user.pyc
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── runtime.py
│   │   ├── runtime.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   └── settings.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── models
│       ├── base.py
│       ├── base.pyc
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── order.py
│       ├── order.pyc
│       ├── product.py
│       ├── product.pyc
│       ├── user.py
│       ├── user.pyc
│       ├── views.py
│       └── views.pyc
├── sfecadmin.py
├── templates
│   └── index.html
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── user_test.py
├── tree.txt
└── uml_diagram.png

10 directories, 63 files
```

And that's how blue print is called inside of executable server.py(pieces of code):

```
from sfec.api.user import register_user_resource
from sfec.controllers.user import user_api
app.register_blueprint(user_api, url_prefix='/api')
```

And user.py file (./sfec/controllers/user.py) contain(pieces of code):

```
user_api = Blueprint('user_api', __name__)
@user_api.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    print "login page"
    """Log the user in."""
    store = get_default_store()
    user = User.authenticate(store, request.form['email'],request.form['password'])
    if user:
        session['user'] = user.id
        return user.json()
    abort(403)
```

The 'login' route is create, so I would expect after navigating to 'localhost:500/login' to receive something back, at least an error 403 or something, but not 404(not found) error.

Can you please help me to understand what am I missing?
I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: If by "navigating" you mean "opening in browser" that makes perfect sense. There is only "POST" verb defined on `/login` endpoint and browser sends GET request.

Comment: ou, shut... you are right. By opening `/login` in browser it makes sense why i don't get anything. But even if i try "navigating" to `/login_check` which has a GET method i still get 404(Not found).

Comment: I think you should navigate to /api/login_check

Comment: Oh,  you are absolutely right. It worked when i have navigated /api/login or /api/login_check. Thank you, now i see what i have missed!